# Resharper 'build solution' shortcut not working

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I recently installed the ReSharper Extension in my Visual Studio and since then the shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + B) for 'build solution' does not work anymore. Maybe some others but I dont know of it yet^^

What I see/tried already:

- When right-clicking my solution the shortcut is shown at the right side of the context menu entry "build solution"
- I reset the key binding in the Visual Studio options

In my ReSharper settings I have the following stuff selected:

Environment > Keyboad > Shortcut Scheme:

- Visual Studio is selected
- Enable Shortcut Browser is disabled
- Use "Alt + R" ... is enabled

Environment > Keyboad > Visual Studio Commands:

- Override Visual Studio Settings refactorings is enabled
- Simplify Visual Studio Menus is enabled
- All Edit.XXX, Refactor.XXX, View.XXX are enabled

Can you tell me what Im missing?

Comment: Is the problem still relevant? If so, please check the "Ctrl+Shift+B" shortcut at "Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard". Click the "Press shortcut keys" field, hit "Ctrl+Shift+B" shortcut and check the action bound to the shortcut at "Shortcut currently used by" field. What action does VS actually have set for it? Is this the Build.BuildSolution action?